# Sitecore - Edge Based Personalization - Move personalization to be handled by CDN

Tags: sxa, personalization, caching, experience-edge, edge

I recently asked about the personalization and why it fails sometimes when using Cloudflare caching. I have come to a conclusion that the way we have set up the personalization is based on using `origin-based personalization`. I have also read that there is the `edge-based personalization` which basically means that the "edge" is CDN and that the CDN serves everything regarding the personalization.

Has anybody done this? Can someone try to explain what needs to be done to set up the personalization using `edge-based`?

Currently we do have the regular personalization at a component level. Is there any way to change that, so that we have the `edge-based personalization`?

### Personalized component on the Home Page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a known limitation that the Experience Edge publishes a static snapshot of the Layout Service output for an item at the time of publishing. This means that the Experience Edge DOES NOT:

1. execute the Sitecore personalisation rules;
2. run the content testing;
3. support the dynamic output from the Layout Service based on the user context, query string params etc.

Today's alternative to the classic Sitecore DXP personalisation offering will be the [Sitecore CDP](https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp) and [Sitecore Personalize](https://www.sitecore.com/products/personalize) products.

In case you have a statically generated content on your website that you consider in scope for your personalisation, you can use the Edge Middleware. It will execute your custom logic or redirect before a request is processed on your site. Read more [here](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/edge-middleware).